# Cocke-Younger-Kasami (CYK) algorithem for the word $baabb$

Tags: algorithms, context-free, formal-grammars, parsers

With the context-free grammar in Chomsky's form:$$S\to BA|AC|b\\A\to AA|AB|CC|a\\B\to AS|BB|CA\\C\to AB|SS|b$$

I need to:

> 1. run the CYK (Cocke-Younger-Kasami) algorithm and decide if I can derive the word $baabb$ from the context.
> 2. write the left derivation.

**My try:**

$1.$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
i\bigg/j &  1 & 2 & 3 &  4 & 5 \\
\hline
1 & \text{C,S} & \text{B} & \square& \square &\square \\
2 & \quad\blacksquare & \text{A} & \text{A} & \square & \square \\
3 & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \text{A} & \text{S,B} & \square \\
4 & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \text{C,S} & \text{A,C} \\
5 & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \text{C,S} \\
\end{array}
$$

2. $S\Longrightarrow BA \Longrightarrow CAA \Longrightarrow bAA\Longrightarrow bAACC\Longrightarrow baabb$

I'm stuck here in the table construction. How should I fill in the empty squares?

Comment: The algorithm is very explicit. What specifically goes wrong when you try to follow the steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYsxXgDxl-U) video and you should get:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
i\bigg/j &  1 & 2 & 3 &  4 & 5 \\
\hline
1 & \text{C,S} & \text{B} & \text{B,S} & \text{A,B,C} & \text{B,C,$\color{red}{\text{S}}$,A} \\
2 & \quad\blacksquare & \text{A} & \text{A} & \text{B,C,A,S} & \text{A,B,C} \\
3 & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \text{A} & \text{S,B} & \text{A,S,C} \\
4 & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \text{C,S} & \text{A,C} \\
5 & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \quad\blacksquare & \text{C,S} \\
\end{array}
$$

Since S is in the left and higher corner so we can derivate the word $baabb$ from the context

Comment: Please include the explanation provided in the video inside your answer. If the video goes down your answer has no use for future visitors.